# Some json parsing error in android using volley and json

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

i am getting some paring error while running this code but i can not tell what is the problem .there is no error in the android studio syntax but there is a problem in the json parsing or with my Json as i am not able to understand how to call json object inside another json object and json arrays

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.TimePicker;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.DatePicker;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
 import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
 import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
 import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
 import com.google.gson.Gson;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 public class BookFragment extends Fragment {
     OneRestaurantBean restaurentinfo;
String placid="ChIJO3JIy9iDGjkRIekztZhsmGg";
PhotosBean photolist;
ReviewBean reviewlist;
StringRequest stringRequest;
Spinner table_for;
PhotosBean photolist;
ReviewBean reviewlist;
private String format = "";
TextView date,time;
int day,month,year,hour,minute;
String url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid="+placeid+"&key=AIzaSyDGtQbIzeOGRk0kGq3rCy3xAvo1xVNB304";

      TextView txtaddress,txtphone,txttiming;
ImageView image1,image2,image3;

// Executes the Request
RequestQueue requestQueue;
ProgressDialog pd;
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book, container, false);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    table_for=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    date=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewdate) ;
   // timePicker1=(TimePicker)view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker2);
    time=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textviewtime);

    txtaddress=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewaddress);
    txtphone=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewphone);
    txttiming=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTiming);

    image1=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    image2=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    image3=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

    init();
   getRestaurentsinfo();
    return view;
}

private void init() {
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =      ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.Table_for, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);


         adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    table_for.setAdapter(adapter);
}

  private void getRestaurentsinfo() {

    stringRequest = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, url,
            new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                   // pd.dismiss();
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);                               
                       Gson gson = new Gson();
                       restaurentinfo =  gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), OneRestaurantBean.class);
   Type listType = new TypeToken<List<PhotosBean>>(){}.getType();
                       photolist = (PhotosBean) gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), listType);
                       Type listType2 = new TypeToken<List<ReviewBean>>(){}.getType();
                      reviewlist = (ReviewBean) gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), listType2);
                        txtaddress.setText(restaurentinfo.getVicinity());                         txttiming.setText(Arrays.toString(restaurentinfo.getOpenhour().getWeekday_text()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));

} catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Some JSON Parsing Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },
            // failure
            new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Some Volley Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
    );

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

my json file is as displayed below

```
 {
      "html_attributions" : [],
     "result" : {
         "address_components" : [
          {
        "long_name" : "Ludhiana",
        "short_name" : "Ludhiana",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Sarabha Nagar",
        "short_name" : "Sarabha Nagar",
        "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Ludhiana",
        "short_name" : "Ludhiana",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Punjab",
        "short_name" : "PB",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "India",
        "short_name" : "IN",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "141003",
        "short_name" : "141003",
        "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
     }
  ],
  "adr_address" : "SCF-21, Sarabha Nagar Market, \u003cspan class=\"extended-address\"\u003eSarabha Nagar\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eLudhiana\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003ePunjab\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e141003\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eIndia\u003c/span\u003e",
  "formatted_address" : "SCF-21, Sarabha Nagar Market, Sarabha Nagar, Ludhiana, Punjab 141003, India",
  "formatted_phone_number" : "0161 245 2810",
  "geometry" : {
     "location" : {
        "lat" : 30.8927238,
        "lng" : 75.8218431
     }
  },
  "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
  "id" : "17865244baa6a88165cbe83f21d2713656bcece0",
  "international_phone_number" : "+91 161 245 2810",
  "name" : "Domino's Pizza",
  "opening_hours" : {
     "open_now" : false,
     "periods" : [
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 0,
              "time" : "2300"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 0,
              "time" : "1100"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 1,
              "time" : "2300"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 1,
              "time" : "1100"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 2,
              "time" : "2300"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 2,
              "time" : "1100"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 3,
              "time" : "2300"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 3,
              "time" : "1100"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 4,
              "time" : "2300"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 4,
              "time" : "1100"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 5,
              "time" : "2300"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 5,
              "time" : "1100"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 6,
              "time" : "2300"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 6,
              "time" : "1100"
           }
        }
     ],
     "weekday_text" : [
        "Monday: 11:00 AM – 11:00 PM",
        "Tuesday: 11:00 AM – 11:00 PM",
        "Wednesday: 11:00 AM – 11:00 PM",
        "Thursday: 11:00 AM – 11:00 PM",
        "Friday: 11:00 AM – 11:00 PM",
        "Saturday: 11:00 AM – 11:00 PM",
        "Sunday: 11:00 AM – 11:00 PM"
     ]
  },
  "photos" : [
     {
        "height" : 1836,
        "html_attributions" : [
           "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102359458524790058006/photos\"\u003eKAMALJEET SINGH RANDHAWA\u003c/a\u003e"
        ],
        "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAIhIrZLQ_Z3H9UUm8Hu96z7N5L4HdKPd_IJbGNEfzW_v2c6zNe3bSYoz3Ya2XkoBHM_9bXBmKbw72d8N_vmFPyT14uqWCHz_WuLWGp_K0Ss-u7VCghzyUpVZ1F5-asNOeTCNLOwjre0FdO8rQsgb4slyJhMGgJg8Okogx_jlShuLEhDdW69Zmuh-aB-SCdI0XdFDGhT4zjH4vKwmgNYkWdcnY53bwD4eaA",
        "width" : 3264
     },
     {
        "height" : 600,
        "html_attributions" : [
           "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109327830988106108854/photos\"\u003eNirwal Karm\u003c/a\u003e"
        ],
        "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAAPpyo99c8N-lt7F-l3YA7qSK7mZKY8zIyaMUoV3OqgOJ9DXVqspqpMQwIvu7KDycvrWcHpy6jaCpc2UyDm3SqtYhw2Fsr5IfgKjKbRTjDF-ST5a9w1vNs44O3SbHWwSLuKV6fhyax1xfqc2TEM7XqAE3K2XSOg5XCzgD8Nef3NJuEhAhTK3UI_yW-dim4bXP4ZK0GhQCO7kgf4E1f53t-_Tf4DEsjYF5xw",
        "width" : 800
     }
  ],
  "place_id" : "ChIJAQAAwM2DGjkR6gVuwpeWwKk",
  "price_level" : 1,
  "rating" : 4.1,
  "reference" : "CmRSAAAATiwel1VKVuyHEFkgl2LEMsL_Rxf9xV3EXj_N_o59Q0ZWGgy-XRjCTmFAPK6z1xRof9WpAKu9FTu-XaNyx6zxGlnzXVNRf-KUOjw-xBB5YdrdDN1VW7eN3E-qw6-pKdXREhCr9EeBMjBidk_KW74s9S9aGhS4NLG4UNMqWveymd0sBkpcieyybg",
  "reviews" : [
     {
        "aspects" : [
           {
              "rating" : 2,
              "type" : "overall"
           }
        ],
        "author_name" : "Vardaan Sharma",
        "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/116622040002550992578",
        "language" : "en",
        "profile_photo_url" : "//lh4.googleusercontent.com/-oc3UC8zHbqE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACDE/eD2qok-jrMQ/photo.jpg",
        "rating" : 4,
        "text" : "Love The Garlic Bread!! Awesome Taste for Decent Prices!!!",
        "time" : 1465754538
     },
     {
        "aspects" : [
           {
              "rating" : 0,
              "type" : "overall"
           }
        ],
        "author_name" : "Darleen Grewal",
        "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/102174339060680368258",
        "language" : "en",
        "rating" : 1,
        "text" : "Pathetic delivery service , orders delayed by one and a half hour and staff is uneducated and non Cooperating",
        "time" : 1476727634
     },
     {
        "aspects" : [
           {
              "rating" : 2,
              "type" : "overall"
           }
        ],
        "author_name" : "Abhishek Attri",
        "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/103724862705815258945",
        "language" : "en",
        "profile_photo_url" : "//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8XVYso4qYxc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAHIA/63UVRnCpc8M/photo.jpg",
        "rating" : 4,
        "text" : "Nice place.. ",
        "time" : 1478198571
     },
     {
        "aspects" : [
           {
              "rating" : 0,
              "type" : "overall"
           }
        ],
        "author_name" : "Bhavesh Bansal",
        "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/107902290149968294793",
        "language" : "en",
        "profile_photo_url" : "//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-0GAn_nkPa9g/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAro/1Z2WU1Tup7g/photo.jpg",
        "rating" : 1,
        "text" : "Poor service. Last 2 orders have been delayed by almost 2 hours. All their contact numbers are unreachable or busy, when you try to contact them.\nSeems like they dont care anymore about customer",
        "time" : 1463848060
     },
     {
        "aspects" : [
           {
              "rating" : 0,
              "type" : "overall"
           }
        ],
        "author_name" : "Gurmeet Gujral",
        "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/113150303121450342768",
        "language" : "en",
        "profile_photo_url" : "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-zzCCjI2B4HU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAJ0w/JOBa4Aetq3E/photo.jpg",
        "rating" : 1,
        "text" : "Don't call them for home delivery. They will serve you cold",
        "time" : 1439473587
     }
  ],
  "scope" : "GOOGLE",
  "types" : [
     "meal_delivery",
     "meal_takeaway",
     "restaurant",
     "food",
     "point_of_interest",
     "establishment"
  ],
  "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=12231942166484485610",
  "utc_offset" : 330,
  "vicinity" : "SCF-21, Sarabha Nagar Market, Ludhiana",
  "website" : "http://www.dominos.co.in/"
       },
     "status" : "OK"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found error in json parsing,use some other parsing method such as
>   Retrofit . Volley JSON Parsing Sample Example

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: Thanks for the link it really helped